# how to add values of List<> in one form to other form's combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have 2 forms, One of them is for Personnel Adding, another one is for Personnel Removing.

I put several textboxes in Personnel Adding form to add a personnel and a button to save it.

But it saves the personnel into `List<Personel>`  ,

Personnel Removing form just has one combobox, I want it to show my List<> values in this combobox.

(by the way i searched couple of times but could not find the exact solution)

Comment: You can define the `List<Personel>` to be public and access it in the Personnell Removing form

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `PersonnelModel` with the `List<Personnel>` defined as a property that both forms reference. This model would need to be instantiated by the main form and passed to the child forms either via the constructor or a public property on the forms.

Hope that helps,
Rob